# Update records Nhibernate and Iqueryable

Tags: c#, nhibernate, c#-4.0, repository-pattern, iqueryable

Let say if i want to update all rows of a table having some status with another status.I am using a Repository pattern with Nhibernate .I have a method in my repository to get me an `Iqueryable<T>`.

So how do i write the update for that.I dont want to get all the elements ,convert to List and then update it.In fact i dont even want Nhibernate to select me the list of rows.
it just need to run an update statement alone in the DB with the values i provide.

so how i can i acheive that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate supports this type of bulk update via HQL.  See http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct.  Try something along the lines of this...

```
public class ThingRepository : Repository<Thing>, IThingRepository
{
    public int UpdateStatus(ThingStatus oldStatus, ThingStatus newStatus)
    {
        var query = Session.CreateQuery("UPDATE Thing SET Status = :newStatus WHERE Status = :oldStatus")
            .SetEnum("oldStatus", oldStatus)
            .SetEnum("newStatus", newStatus);

        return query.ExecuteUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: makes sense.. But i need to have a ref to my session in ThingRepository which i dont have . I have it only in my Repository<Thing>....

Comment: hey ashley, this is the correct answer. I see what you're saying about wanting to update off the IQueryable, but then you're missing the point about what a sql update is. An IQueryable is a deferred "select" statement. an update is a scalar call, a write only operation. If you really want to call update off IQueryable you could write an extension method, but you'd still have to access the session, and possible execute the IQueryable too (unless you examined the expression tree which would not be a trivial task at all)